# C# convert dates to Timestamp

Tags: c#, timestamp

I got a date in the below format:
2014-07-18

I need the unixTimeStamp of this date like PHP gives. I want to store those in a msAccess table which I can later sort on this timestamp value.

PHP returns this timestamp for the above date:
1405641600

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is that timestamp correct? It should be 1405641600 http://unixtimesta.mp/1405641600

Comment: You are right. I updated the timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep I think Anthony Chu is correct. I used the following site to check:

http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

And it gave the answer 1405641600.

I also did the following C# to get the same answer for your example date:

```
var baseDate = new DateTime (1970, 01, 01);
var toDate = new DateTime (2014, 07, 18);
var numberOfSeconds = toDate.Subtract (baseDate).TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually i use this extension:

```
public static class Extensions
{
     public static  double ToUnixTime(this DateTime input)
     {
         return input.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalSeconds;
     }
}
```

As you mention in question, you need PHP like TimeStamp, so you will need to round `TotalSeconds`(it's double right now):

```
public static class Extensions
{
     public static int ToUnixTime(this DateTime input)
     {
         return (int)input.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalSeconds;
     }
}
```